# Read json from text file

Tags: java, android, json

Im trying  to make an app that reads json from a web service, saves it to a file and then reads the file and parses the json.

The reason for saving the file is that im going to read several json sources which all have the same layout.

Code:

```
public void lesstatusDescription(String sporingsnummer) {
    InputStream oFile;
    try {
        oFile = openFileInput(sporingsnummer + ".json");
        InputStreamReader oReader = new InputStreamReader(oFile);
        BufferedReader oBuffer = new BufferedReader(oReader);
        String sText = "";
        String sEachLine = "";
        while ((sEachLine = oBuffer.readLine()) != null) {
            sText += sEachLine;
        }
        oReader.close();
        final JSONObject object = new JSONObject(sText);
        JSONArray consignmentSet = object.getJSONArray("consignmentSet");
        Integer i = consignmentSet.length();
        TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        tv.setText(i.toString());

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        //handle exception here
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),ex.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

I seem to get the error: 
`org.json.JSONException: Value The of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject`

Edit : 
Added json file :

```
{"consignmentSet":[{"consignmentId":"70300490908546098","previousConsignmentId":"","totalWeightInKgs":0.0,"totalVolumeInDm3":1.2,"packageSet":[{"statusDescription":"","descriptions":[],"packageNumber":"RA608072968SG","previousPackageNumber":"","productName":"REKOMMANDERT BREV FRA UTLANDET","productCode":"2567","brand":"POSTEN","lengthInCm":32,"widthInCm":12,"heightInCm":3,"volumeInDm3":1.2,"weightInKgs":0.0,"dateOfReturn":"03.07.2013","recipientAddress":{"addressLine1":"","addressLine2":"","postalCode":"1458","city":"FJELLSTRAND","countryCode":"NO","country":"Norway"},"eventSet":[{"description":"Sendingen er utlevert","status":"DELIVERED","recipientSignature":{"name":""},"unitId":"171108","unitType":"BRING","postalCode":"1450","city":"NESODDTANGEN","countryCode":"NO","country":"Norway","dateIso":"2013-06-20T15:08:48+02:00","displayDate":"20.06.2013","displayTime":"15:08","consignmentEvent":false},{"description":"Sendingen er ankommet <a title=\"Her finner du Nesoddtangen postkontor\" href=\"https://www.posten.no/kundeservice/postkontor-info-iframe?enhetsnr=171108\" class=\"sporing-lightbox-postoffice\">Nesoddtangen postkontor</a>","status":"READY_FOR_PICKUP","recipientSignature":{"name":""},"unitId":"171108","unitInformationUrl":"http://fraktguide.bring.no/fraktguide/api/pickuppoint/id/171108","unitType":"BRING","postalCode":"1451","city":"NESODDTANGEN","countryCode":"NO","country":"Norway","dateIso":"2013-06-19T08:35:21+02:00","displayDate":"19.06.2013","displayTime":"08:35","consignmentEvent":false},{"description":"Sendingen er ankommet terminal og blir videresendt","status":"IN_TRANSIT","recipientSignature":{"name":""},"unitId":"032850","unitType":"BRING","postalCode":"0024","city":"OSLO","countryCode":"NO","country":"Norway","dateIso":"2013-06-18T16:37:13+02:00","displayDate":"18.06.2013","displayTime":"16:37","consignmentEvent":false,"definitions":[{"term":"terminal","explanation":"Brev, pakke eller godsterminal som benyttes til sortering  og omlasting av sendinger som er underveis til mottaker."}]},{"description":"Sendingen er tollbehandlet og sendes til mottaker.","status":"IN_TRANSIT","recipientSignature":{"name":""},"unitId":"032874","unitType":"BRING","postalCode":"0024","city":"OSLO","countryCode":"NO","country":"Norway","dateIso":"2013-06-18T13:44:56+02:00","displayDate":"18.06.2013","displayTime":"13:44","consignmentEvent":false,"definitions":[{"term":"mottaker","explanation":"En person eller firma som fÃ¥r en sending tilsendt er mottaker. Kalles ogsÃ¥ adressat. Det vil si den som avsender adresserer sendingen til."}]},{"description":"Sendingen er antatt tollpliktig og er sendt til tollbehandling","status":"CUSTOMS","recipientSignature":{"name":""},"unitId":"100838","unitType":"BRING","postalCode":"1470","city":"LÃ˜RENSKOG","countryCode":"NO","country":"Norway","dateIso":"2013-06-17T12:34:28+02:00","displayDate":"17.06.2013","displayTime":"12:34","consignmentEvent":false,"definitions":[{"term":"tollbehandling","explanation":"Bestiller du varer fra utlandet, for eksempel pÃ¥ utenlandske nettsteder, mÃ¥ du fortolle varene. Vi utfÃ¸rer denne tjenesten for deg. \r\nSkal du sende varer utenfor Norges grenser, mÃ¥ sendingene fÃ¸rst tollbehandles. Avhengig av vareverdi og innhold kan det kreves at sendingen eksportdeklareres (fortolles)."},{"term":"antatt tollpliktig","explanation":"En sending som antas Ã¥ ha tollpliktig innhold. Sendingen gÃ¥r videre til tollkontroll. Det betyr ikke nÃ¸dvendigvis at mottaker mÃ¥ betale toll eller moms, men sendingen blir kontrollert for Ã¥ avgjÃ¸re dette. "}]},{"description":"Sendingen er ankommet mottakerlandet","status":"INTERNATIONAL","recipientSignature":{"name":""},"unitId":"100838","unitType":"BRING","postalCode":"","city":"OSLO LETTER CENTER","countryCode":"NO","country":"Norway","dateIso":"2013-06-17T11:41:48+02:00","displayDate":"17.06.2013","displayTime":"11:41","consignmentEvent":false},{"description":"Sendingen er sendt fra avsenderland","status":"INTERNATIONAL","recipientSignature":{"name":""},"unitId":"032858","unitType":"BRING","postalCode":"","city":"SINGAPORE SÃ˜5","countryCode":"SG","country":"Singapore","dateIso":"2013-06-14T11:22:00+02:00","displayDate":"14.06.2013","displayTime":"11:22","consignmentEvent":false,"definitions":[{"term":"avsenderland","explanation":"Det landet en sendingen er innlevert og sendt ifra."}]},{"description":"Sendingen er ankommet eksportterminal","status":"INTERNATIONAL","recipientSignature":{"name":""},"unitId":"032858","unitType":"BRING","postalCode":"","city":"SINGAPORE SÃ˜5","countryCode":"SG","country":"Singapore","dateIso":"2013-06-13T21:06:00+02:00","displayDate":"13.06.2013","displayTime":"21:06","consignmentEvent":false},{"description":"Sendingen er sendt fra avsenderland","status":"INTERNATIONAL","recipientSignature":{"name":""},"unitId":"032858","unitType":"BRING","postalCode":"","city":"SINGAPORE SÃ˜5","countryCode":"SG","country":"Singapore","dateIso":"2013-06-13T21:06:00+02:00","displayDate":"13.06.2013","displayTime":"21:06","consignmentEvent":false,"definitions":[{"term":"avsenderland","explanation":"Det landet en sendingen er innlevert  og sendt ifra."}]}]}]}]}
```

What im i doing wrong ?

Comment: check your final `sText`. It might not be in proper JSON format.

Comment: apparently your JSON file's content is not proper, can you provide your JSON file?

Comment: Provided the JSON file. now i suddenly get a NullPointerException.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem. Log and check what you get from the JSON. If your JSON is not valid, it won't work just fix your file but if your json is valid, try changing your line like this: (increment and try till substring(5))

```
final JSONObject object = new JSONObject(sText.substring(1));
```

Comment: so lame and so true :)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps Your sText variable is appending some character which is making you JSON string invalid. print sText and verify it on http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com.

Comment: Please check if any key is duplicated.

Answer (score 0):

Your sText is not proper formatted in json, validate it before parsing

Comment: shouldn't it be a comment rather than an answer?